# Check string matching with regular expression within PHP/Smarty-Template

Tags: php, regex, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I want to check within an if query whether a particular string (WBT) occurs in a string and responds to it. I know that it is possible to work with regular expressions within Smarty templates, but it is not clear with the suggestions from the [documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl).

Here is the code where I need the regular expression to check if the string WBT occurs in it:

```
<div class="card-content" style="text-align: center;">
   [{if $woche.lehrskript}] // Check if "WBT" occurs in the string lehrskript
     <strong>WBT</string>
   [{else}]
     <strong>[{$woche.lehrskript.name}]</strong>
   [{/if}]
</div>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I havent used smarty but you cant just use PHP's `strpos`?

Comment: Why not just use PHP inside smarty?

Comment: @hungrykoala .how? Is there really no smarty solution? I'm working in a very old environment with complex code and i really don't know where else I can realize this stuff..

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it that way:

```
[{if strpos($woche.lehrskript.name, 'WBT') != false}]
```